# What would you call a cable which combines both a coaxial transmission line and regular conductors?

Tags: cables, coax, coaxial

I'm looking for a cable that can carry both dual supply (+5V and -5V at <100mA) DC power and a relatively high bandwidth analog signal. The intended application is powering the amplifier of an active probe.

Problem is, I don't know what to call such a thing, so I have difficulty finding anything. Is this such a niche product that realistically you have to custom order it from a manufacturer at great expense? I did find out that some shops specializing in CCTV equipment sell RG59 with two extra power conductors attached as "siamese coax", but that term seems to be exclusively used in the context of closed circuit television.

To be clear, I'm asking for clarification regarding terminology, not any specific products.

Comment: “Not a very cost effective cable”

Comment: a search for "mixed coaxial cable" finds several examples

Comment: The keyword "hybrid" as in "hybrid coaxial cable" also seems to bring some relevant results. Nonetheless, they seem to be quite rare. Might have to settle for a sleeve with two wires and a coax inside.

Comment: If you see "Discontinued product, we can find a similar product" it mean's low demand , not cost effective. Yet there are many other ways to bundle pairs of cable as done in aircraft, automobile wiring.  I suggest you see how it's done.  Waxed nylon string , weaving a nylon jacket from 2 spools.  It depends on your budget  and demand.  In the old days I would put DC on the coax and have power, duplex audio intercom, 2 way SCADA data and remote controlled TV on VHF. all on one coax.

Comment: Yet your application seems low volume and you need special coax for low phase shift, wide bandwidth

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I figured as much, the niche seems to be too small for this product to exist. I did briefly consider either DC biasing the coax or putting an out of band sine wave down the coax and rectifying at the probe end into DC. The former prevents DC coupling, the latter requires generating high amplitude RF and complex filtering. Neither is a good solution.

Comment: Why not put the probe on a 10 MHz FM carrier and power on DC?